# Calculate the distribution of $(\cos(\min(X,Y)),\max(X,Y))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y$ be iid distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$, my task involves calculating the distribution of $(\cos(\min(X,Y)),\max(X,Y))$ I have already calculated the distribution of $(\min(X,Y),\max(X,Y))$, its density is $2\text {    for   } y \leq x$, where $y$ denotes $\min$, $x$ denotes $\max$.

I managed to do it myslef, later i will post my anwser.